# Akka.actor.dispatcher NoSuchMethod exception

Tags: scala, akka, sbt-assembly

I am trying to learn about Akka actors and I am running the following example. My problem is that when I run though the Idea IDE it works perfectly fine. But when I run it using the jar created by sbt assembly it throws a  `NoSuchMethodException  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContextExecutor`  Exception which I cannot debug because it works fine in the IDE.

```
object Runner {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
       run()
}

def run() = {
val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
import system.dispatcher
val props = Props[Manager]
val pool = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(Int, ActorRef)]
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  pool += ((i, system.actorOf(props)))
}

val futures = pool.map {
  case (x: Int, y: ActorRef) =>
    val future = ask(y, Echo(x))(Timeout(100 seconds)).mapTo[Int]
    println(future.toString)
    future

}
/*Next line causes Exception*/
val futureList = Future.sequence(futures)
val result = futureList.map(x => {
  x.sum
})

result onSuccess {
  case sum => println(sum)
}

pool.foreach(x => system.stop(x._2))
system.shutdown()

 }
}
```

The sbt file I am using is the following.

```
 lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "foobar",
  version := "1.0",
   scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
   test in assembly := {}
 )

 lazy val root = (project).aggregate(redis).settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
 name := "scala_code_root",
 version := "1.0",
 scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
 exportJars := false
  )

lazy val myakka =(project in file("myakka")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(   
  libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.15"
)
```

The exception is thrown at the line `val futureList = Future.sequence(futures)`. Apparently the method is trere because both IDEA and sbt-assembly use the same sbt file. What could be the cause of the Exception?

Comment: How are you generating and running the jar? The problem is that the class isn't on your runtime classpath - so it's either missing from the jar, or your classpath is wrong.

Comment: I am using the sbt file and sbt-assembly to create a fat jar that contains all dependencies. the command I am running is scala -cp /path/to/fat/jar/ Runner

Comment: The version of `akka.actor.ActorSystem` that's bundled in your fat jar is not the same as what you compiled against. Typically, `sbt-assembly` makes you specify how to handle multiple class files being bundled together. Do you have any configuration for `sbt-assembly` in another file?

Comment: I have the sbt file that is shown above.

Comment: How are you running `sbt-assembly`? If you're running it on the root project, it may fail to bundle transitive dependencies of child projects.

Comment: I am running it on the root project but sbt creates a separate jar for `myakka` and I am using that one i.e. `./myakka/target/scala-2.10/myakka.jar.` The command is therefore scala -cp `./myakka/target/scala-2.10/myakka.jar.`Runner. What is strange is that the classes are included in the fat jar and other classes of the file are used with no problem.

Comment: Right, the classes are included - but the error indicates you're using the wrong *version* of the class. What's included in the fat jar isn't the class version you compiled against.